# Crash in PyScripter with PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyscripter

I begin to use PYQT and my IDE PyScripter is systematically closed when I launch for the second time ! Even for very simple code like :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import QLabel, QApplication

if __name__=='__main__':
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Label = QLabel( "Hello World!" )
    Label.show()
    App.exec_()
```

PyScripter Version 2.4.1.0 ; Python 2.7.1 ; PyQT4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Remote Engine. See http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/wiki/RemoteEngines

Comment: Very good ! I thought it was the default option but no. It's OK now.